# Javascript: two different objects sharing an array property?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

In my JavaScript project I define an object, then create multiple instances using Object.create(). The object has several (string and int) properties, each of which is unique per instance. However, if I use an array property, all instances share the same array.

This code easily demonstrates this:

```
TestThing = {
    code: "?",
    intlist: [],

    addint(i) {
        alert("Adding " + i + " to " + this.code + ", list had " + this.intlist.length + " ints");
        this.intlist.push(i);
    }
}

var thing1 = Object.create(TestThing);
thing1.code = "Thing 1";
var thing2 = Object.create(TestThing);
thing2.code = "Thing 2";

thing1.addint(11);
thing2.addint(42);

alert(thing2.intlist);  // will output 11,42
```

So, what causes this? How do I solve this issue?

Comment: *"The object has several (string and int) properties, each of which is unique per instance."* - no, it's just that you treat them in a different way. `thing1.code = "Thing 1";` is fundamentally different to `thing1.intlist.push(11);`. One's modifying, one's replacing.

Comment: The inner array is not a copy..it is a reference to original array

Comment: So how do I make sure each instance has it's own array? edit: I mean I know how to replace the array with a new ne per instance, but that's not very elegant. What would be best practice in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With reference-type properties, each child gets a reference to the same object. Any change any child makes to the object are visible to all instances.

You need to either implement a constructor to set up the property, or have the code that uses the property set it up the first time through. (If you want to use a constructor *and* `Object.create`, though, you'll have to call it yourself; `Object.create` won't call it for you.)

You could do something like this...

```
TestThing = {
    code: "?",
    intlist: null,
    addint : (i) => {
        if (!this.intlist) this.intlist = [];
        alert("Adding " + i + " to " + this.code + ", list had " + this.intlist.length + " ints");
        this.intlist.push(i);
    }
}
```

Or, less error-prone-ly (albeit forsaking `Object.create`)...

```
class TestThing {
    constructor(code) {
        this.code = code;
        this.intlist = [];
    }

    addint(i) {
        alert("Adding " + i + " to " + this.code + ", list had " + this.intlist.length + " ints");
        this.intlist.push(i);
    }
}

var thing1 = new TestThing("Thing 1");
var thing2 = new TestThing("Thing 2");

thing1.addint(11);
thing2.addint(42);

alert(thing2.intlist);  // will output 42
```

Unfortunately, if you're coding for web browsers, IE (even IE 11) doesn't seem to support `class`. So you'll have to stick with the old way of defining classes.

```
TestThing = function(code) {
    this.code = code;
    this.intlist = [];
};

TestThing.prototype = {
    addint: function(i) {
        alert("Adding " + i + " to " + this.code + ", list had " + this.intlist.length + " ints");
        this.intlist.push(i);
    }
};
```

Comment: I can see how this works around the issue, but this solution becomes almost unworkable if I have a lot of functions (or even other objects) accessing the property. I was hoping for a way to create the inheriting objects without running into this problem.

Comment: That'd be a job for a constructor. Unfortunately, if you use `Object.create`, it won't call the constructor for you.

Comment: @cHao however the second parameter may help: `const instance = Object.create(parent, {list: [] });`

Comment: Thanks @cHao, I'll think I'll switch to the more elegant way in your second example.

Comment: @Jonasw: That second argument to `Object.create` isn't quite as cool as it first looks. (Its values are supposed to be property descriptors.) Plus, it's still error-prone, though. You could, if you wanted, say `Object.new = function(parent, ...args) { let retval = Object.create(parent); retval.constructor(...args); return retval; }`, if you wanted.

Comment: But, that `Object.new` doesn't add any support for inheritance more than one level deep.

Answer (score -2):

To fix this you use `concat` instead of push, like so:

`this.intlist = this.intlist.concat(i);`

Why this happens ? Because `push` mutates the array, `concat` doesn't, and an array in javascript is also an object, hence, the memory reference to that array is the same.

Comment: I feel this is a dangerous way to do this - all instances will still share the same array until they add something to it. I want to use the array in several ways, not just this one function. Your solution seems error-prone, and inefficient if I use the add function a lot (say, 10,000's of times).

Comment: you can also use Object.assign({}, TestThing) or use spread operator to add to the list.

Comment: But the problem is not adding things to the list (the code is just an example). The problem is that I may have several functions and external objects and functions accessing the property, and using it in several ways. For this, all instances should have their own instance of the array.